# How to position the legend right to donut chart in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, charts, responsive

I am facing the issue to shift the legend outside i.e right to donut chart.I have tried lot of option to shift the legend to right of donut but unable to get right approach.I am using the d3.js library.
please see the image in which I am getting legend in centre of donut chart.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmZu8.png)

d3.js script:-

```
var dataset = [
    { name: 'Data', percent: 100 },
    { name: 'Chrome', percent: 32.51 },
    { name: 'Safari', percent: 23.68 },
    { name: 'Opera', percent: 50.71 },
    { name: 'Firefox', percent: 8.71 },
    { name: 'Others', percent: 36.01 }
];
 
var pie=d3.layout.pie()
  .value(function(d){return d.percent})
  .sort(null)
  .padAngle(.03);
 
var w=500,h=500;
 
var outerRadius=w/2;
var innerRadius=w/3;
 
var color = d3.scale.category10();
 
var arc=d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(outerRadius)
  .innerRadius(innerRadius);
 
var svg=d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr({
      width:w,
      height:h,
      class:'shadow'
  })
  //.style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)")
  .append('g')
  .attr({
      transform:'translate('+w/2+','+h/2+')'
  });

// filters go in defs element
var defs = svg.append("defs");

// create filter with id #drop-shadow
// height=130% so that the shadow is not clipped
var filter = defs.append("filter")
    .attr("id", "drop-shadow")
    .attr("height", "130%");

// SourceAlpha refers to opacity of graphic that this filter will be applied to
// convolve that with a Gaussian with standard deviation 3 and store result
// in blur
filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
    .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
    .attr("stdDeviation", 15)
    .attr("result", "blur");

// translate output of Gaussian blur to the right and downwards with 2px
// store result in offsetBlur
filter.append("feOffset")
    .attr("in", "blur")
    .attr("dx",100)
    .attr("dy", 100)
    .attr("result", "offsetBlur");

// overlay original SourceGraphic over translated blurred opacity by using
// feMerge filter. Order of specifying inputs is important!
var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");

feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
    .attr("in", "offsetBlur")
feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
    .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");


var path=svg.selectAll('path')
  .data(pie(dataset))
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr({
      d:arc,
      fill:function(d,i){
          return color(d.data.name);
      }
  });
 
path.transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attrTween('d', function(d) {
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate({startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0}, d);
      return function(t) {
          return arc(interpolate(t));
      };
  });
 
 
var restOfTheData=function(){
    var text=svg.selectAll('text')
        .data(pie(dataset))
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
        })
        .attr("dy", ".4em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d){
            return d.data.percent+"%";
        })
        .style({
            fill:'#fff',
            'font-size':'10px'
        });
 
    var legendRectSize=20;
    var legendSpacing=7;
    var legendHeight=legendRectSize+legendSpacing;
 
 
    var legend=svg.selectAll('.legend')
        .data(color.domain())
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr({
            class:'legend',
            transform:function(d,i){
                //Just a calculation for x & y position
                return 'translate(-35,' + ((i*legendHeight)-65) + ')';
            }
        });
    legend.append('rect')
        .attr({
            width:legendRectSize,
            height:legendRectSize,
            rx:20,
            ry:20
        })
        .style({
            fill:color,
            stroke:color
        });
 
    legend.append('text')
        .attr({
            x:30,
            y:15
        })
        .text(function(d){
            return d;
        }).style({
            fill:'#929DAF',
            'font-size':'14px'
        });
};
 
setTimeout(restOfTheData,2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are positioning the individual parts of your legend based on the size of the . You can simplify this by creating a  that contains all of your legend elements and translating that to its desired position in the graph.

You'll need to play around with the values to get exactly what you want, but below are the values that would allow you to place the legend in the right margin.

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 40};

var legendHolder = svg.append('g')
  // translate the holder to the right side of the graph
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + (margin.left + width) + ",0)")

var legend = legendHolder.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Comment: Hi @chrissi1992 ... I am stucked at place while implementing d3.js with angular5. Could you please take a look at my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62940868/show-text-inside-nvd3-half-circle-donut-chart